# Can I use Anaconda for the future?

Tags: anaconda

So basically I started learning python and with Visual Studio Code. It was great till I had to install simple packages(pandas, numpy, etc). I couldn’t get it to work because it was too complicated to change path and all that as I’m a beginner.

This is why I installed Anaconda, like all the modules were there. What I’m worried is about that in the future if I work in a company can I still use anaconda?

Is it common for programmers to use anaconda for module management?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Many enterprises use Anaconda. Anaconda continues to be a very relevant tool in managing python environments. Many tools such as AzureML and other build conda environments as a core component of their backend processes.

You can also try:

- [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)
- [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)